# -bash: $: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to install pyqt on my Mac. I have installed Homebrew and it seems to be "fine" but when I run the command

```
$ brew install pyqt
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction, I have looked at several websites but I can't seem to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you copied a line from a website or other source. Generally, terminal commands are prefixed by a sample terminal prompt in documentation. For example, if you're instructed to run the `ls` command, you'll often see it printed as

```
$ ls
```

in documentation. That `$` is *not* part of the command, it merely represents a terminal prompt.

So run `brew install pyqt` without the `$`.